# Sorting queryset by repeating values ​in django

Tags: python, django, sql-order-by, django-queryset

There is a school with a total of 12 classes.

9-A, 9-B, 9-C
10-A, 10-B,10-C
11-A,11-B,11-C

We have students in each class and I want to order a queryset that contains these students.

We can access the degree and letter of the class separately.

I want to order them like that :

9-A
10-A
11-A
9-B
10-B
11-B
9-C
10-C
11-C

(A B C is not sorted, it should be random. I want to sort 9 10 11.)

It will repeat itself every three times like 9,10,11,9,10,11.

I couldn't figure how to write a query to sort them with this algorithm.

```
students= Student.objects.distinct().filter(exams__schedule_id=1).order_by('')
```

Here is the student queryset. How should I fill order_by part ?

Here is my Student model :

```
class Student(models.Model):

school = models.ForeignKey('School',on_delete=CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE, primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
schoolNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField()
email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
schoolClass = models.ForeignKey('SchoolClass',on_delete=SET_NULL,null=True)
exams = models.ManyToManyField('Exam',blank=True)
phoneNumber = PhoneNumberField(null=True,blank=True)
address = models.OneToOneField('Address', on_delete=SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
```

SchoolClass model :

```
class SchoolClass(models.Model):

school = models.ForeignKey('School',on_delete=CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
degree = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = degree_choices, default = "9")
branch = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = branch_choices, default = "A")
deskPlan = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
floor = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
representative = models.OneToOneField('Student', on_delete = SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
numberOfStudents = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
```

Comment: Can you share your models.py file, just the bit where you show all of the fields for your Student model.

Comment: I added Student and schoolClass models, thank you.

Comment: So you want to order it the related model `schoolClass`'s field `degree` then? `order_by('schoolClass__degree')` will do the job.

Comment: With your suggestion it will sort like this : 9-A 9-B 9-C 10-A 10-B 10-C 11-A 11-B 11-C .

Comment: Right you are, do `order_by('schoolClass__branch', 'schoolClass__degree')`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The degree part should go as a pattern. 9 10 11 9 10 11 9 10 11  for all rows in student table and branch does not matter.

Comment: Well this would work right? If the branch doesn't matter, then it can be in the order, so all the A's can go first. So this would be `9A, 10A, 11A, 9B, 10B, 11B, 9C, 10C, 11C`?